# Creating table in android studio using recyclerview and ListItem

Tags: java, php, android, xml, android-recyclerview

I want to create a table in android using ListItem and RecylerView. I already create it using API but it doesn't showing any data. here is my code

kehadiran.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".kehadiran">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/llViewTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/kehadiran"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="32dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text = "Kehadiran"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/llViewTitle"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerViewDeliveryProductList"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
            tools:listitem="@layout/table_list_item" />

    </HorizontalScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

table_list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txttglabsen"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:background="@drawable/table_content_cell_bg"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtf1"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:background="@drawable/table_content_cell_bg"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtdepoawal"
        android:layout_width="124dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:background="@drawable/table_content_cell_bg"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtshiftmasuk"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:background="@drawable/table_content_cell_bg"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtF4"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:background="@drawable/table_content_cell_bg"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtDepoAkhir"
        android:layout_width="128dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:background="@drawable/table_content_cell_bg"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtKeluar"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:background="@drawable/table_content_cell_bg"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtketerangan"
        android:layout_width="128dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:background="@drawable/table_content_cell_bg"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

TableViewAdapter.java

```
package com.example.eis2.Item;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import com.example.eis2.R;
import java.util.List;

public class TableViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

    private List kehadiranlist;
    public TableViewAdapter(List kehadiranlist, Context applicationContext) {
        this.kehadiranlist = kehadiranlist;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.
                from(parent.getContext()).
                inflate(R.layout.table_list_item, parent, false);

        return new RowViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        RowViewHolder rowViewHolder = (RowViewHolder) holder;

        int rowPos = rowViewHolder.getAdapterPosition();

        if (rowPos == 0) {

            rowViewHolder.txttglabsen.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.table_header_cell_bg);
            rowViewHolder.txtf1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.table_header_cell_bg);
            rowViewHolder.txtdepoawal.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.table_header_cell_bg);
            rowViewHolder.txtshiftmasuk.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.table_header_cell_bg);
            rowViewHolder.txtF4.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.table_header_cell_bg);
            rowViewHolder.txtDepoAkhir.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.table_header_cell_bg);
            rowViewHolder.txtKeluar.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.table_header_cell_bg);
            rowViewHolder.txtketerangan.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.table_header_cell_bg);

            rowViewHolder.txttglabsen.setText("Tanggal Absen");
            rowViewHolder.txtf1.setText("F1");
            rowViewHolder.txtdepoawal.setText("Depo Awal");
            rowViewHolder.txtshiftmasuk.setText("Shift Masuk");
            rowViewHolder.txtF4.setText("F4");
            rowViewHolder.txtDepoAkhir.setText("Depo Akhir");
            rowViewHolder.txtKeluar.setText("Shift Keluar");
            rowViewHolder.txtketerangan.setText("keterangan");
        } else {
            keteranganmodel modal = (keteranganmodel) kehadiranlist.get(rowPos - 1);

            rowViewHolder.txttglabsen.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.table_content_cell_bg);
            rowViewHolder.txtf1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.table_content_cell_bg);
            rowViewHolder.txtdepoawal.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.table_content_cell_bg);
            rowViewHolder.txtshiftmasuk.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.table_content_cell_bg);
            rowViewHolder.txtF4.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.table_content_cell_bg);
            rowViewHolder.txtDepoAkhir.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.table_content_cell_bg);
            rowViewHolder.txtDepoAkhir.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.table_content_cell_bg);
            rowViewHolder.txtketerangan.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.table_content_cell_bg);

            rowViewHolder.txttglabsen.setText(modal.getShift_day() + "");
            rowViewHolder.txtf1.setText(modal.getF1());
            rowViewHolder.txtdepoawal.setText(modal.getDepo_f1() + "");
            rowViewHolder.txtshiftmasuk.setText(modal.getWaktu_masuk() + "");
            rowViewHolder.txtF4.setText(modal.getF4() + "");
            rowViewHolder.txtDepoAkhir.setText(modal.getDepo_f4());
            rowViewHolder.txtKeluar.setText(modal.getWaktu_keluar() + "");
            rowViewHolder.txtketerangan.setText(modal.getKet_absensi() + "");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return kehadiranlist == null ? 0 : kehadiranlist.size();
    }

    public static class RowViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView txttglabsen;
        TextView txtf1;
        TextView txtdepoawal;
        TextView txtshiftmasuk;
        TextView txtF4;
        TextView txtDepoAkhir;
        TextView txtKeluar;
        TextView txtketerangan;

        RowViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            txttglabsen = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txttglabsen);
            txtf1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtf1);
            txtdepoawal = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtdepoawal);
            txtshiftmasuk = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtshiftmasuk);
            txtF4 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtF4);
            txtDepoAkhir = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtDepoAkhir);
            txtKeluar = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtKeluar);
            txtketerangan = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtketerangan);
        }
    }
}
```

kehadiran.java

```
package com.example.eis2;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.example.eis2.Item.TableViewAdapter;
import com.example.eis2.Item.keteranganmodel;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static com.example.eis2.Item.LoginItem.ABSENSI_URL;

public class kehadiran extends AppCompatActivity {
    private List<keteranganmodel> absensi;
    ListView list;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_kehadiran);

        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewDeliveryProductList);

        TableViewAdapter adapter = new TableViewAdapter(getKehadiranlist(), getApplicationContext());

        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        absensi = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    private List getKehadiranlist() {
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, ABSENSI_URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
                            JSONArray keteranganArray = obj.getJSONArray("data");

                            for (int i = 0; i < keteranganArray.length(); i++) {

                                JSONObject keteranganobject = keteranganArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                keteranganmodel keterangan = new keteranganmodel(
                                        keteranganobject.getString("shift_day"),
                                        keteranganobject.getString("f1"),
                                        keteranganobject.getString("depo_f1"),
                                        keteranganobject.getString("waktu_masuk"),
                                        keteranganobject.getString("f4"),
                                        keteranganobject.getString("depo_f4"),
                                        keteranganobject.getString("waktu_keluar"),
                                        keteranganobject.getString("ket_absensi"));

                                absensi.add(keterangan);
                                System.out.println("data:" + keterangan);
                            }
                            TableViewAdapter adapter = new TableViewAdapter(absensi, getApplicationContext());

                            list.setAdapter((ListAdapter) adapter);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
        return absensi;
    }
}
```

keteranganmodel.java

```
package com.example.eis2.Item;

public class keteranganmodel {
    private String shift_day;
    private String f1;
    private String depo_f1;
    private String waktu_masuk;
    private String f4;
    private String depo_f4;
    private String waktu_keluar;
    private String ket_absensi;

    public keteranganmodel(String shift_day, String f1, String depo_f1, String waktu_masuk, String f4, String depo_f4, String waktu_keluar, String ket_absensi) {
        this.shift_day = shift_day;
        this.f1 = f1;
        this.depo_f1 = depo_f1;
        this.waktu_masuk = waktu_masuk;
        this.f4 = f4;
        this.depo_f4 = depo_f4;
        this.waktu_keluar = waktu_keluar;
        this.ket_absensi = ket_absensi;
    }

    public String getShift_day() {
        return shift_day;
    }
    public void setShift_day(String shift_day) { this.shift_day = shift_day; }

    public String getF1() {
        return f1;
    }
    public void setF1(String f1) {
        this.f1 = f1;
    }

    public String getDepo_f1() {
        return depo_f1;
    }
    public void setDepo_f1(String depo_f1) {
        this.depo_f1 = depo_f1;
    }

    public String getWaktu_masuk() {return waktu_masuk;}
    public void setWaktu_masuk(String waktu_masuk) {this.waktu_masuk = waktu_masuk; }

    public String getF4() {
        return f4;
    }
    public void setF4(String f4) {
        this.f4 = f4;
    }

    public String getDepo_f4() {
        return depo_f4;
    }
    public void setDepo_f4(String depo_f4) {
        this.depo_f4 = depo_f4;
    }

    public String getWaktu_keluar() {
        return waktu_keluar;
    }
    public void setKet_absensi(String waktu_keluar) {
        this.waktu_keluar = waktu_keluar;
    }

    public String getKet_absensi() {
        return ket_absensi;
    }
    public void setWaktu_keluar(String ket_absensi) {
        this.ket_absensi = ket_absensi;
    }
}
```

and here is it's API

```
<?php 
function curl($url){
    $ch = curl_init(); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
    $output = curl_exec($ch); 
    curl_close($ch);      
    return $output;
}
$send = curl("http://hrd.tvip.co.id/rest_server/api/absensi/index?shift_day=2020-08-24&shift_day_2=2020-08-27&badgenumber=0100028400");

// mengubah JSON menjadi array
$data = json_decode($send, TRUE);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($data);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

I tried every time but it always blank or no showing data

the main problem is

```
2020-08-31 10:18:16.245 11130-11130/com.example.eis2 W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value <pre>Array of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your php code you are doing `echo <pre>`, the same is also coming in output of your api, kindly remove both `pre` echo statements from your code, use them for debugging your output at php level only.

So in your php code will be like

```
$data = json_decode($send, TRUE);
echo $data;
```